# Реально ли сделать такую анимацию с помощью css?

Tags: css, css3, анимация, css-animation

Добрый день! Есть такая анимация на css:

```css
.online {
  display: block;
 position: relative;
 width: 8px;
 height: 8px;
 border: 1px solid green;
 background: green;
 -webkit-animation: online 2s steps(5, start) infinite;
 -moz-animation: online 2s steps(5, start) infinite;
 animation: online 2s steps(5, start) infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes online { to { visibility: hidden; } }
@-moz-keyframes online { to { visibility: hidden; } }
@keyframes online { to { visibility: hidden; } }
```

```html
<div class="online"></div>
```

А реально ли сделать с помощью css такую анимацию? Если да, то помогите, пожалуйста. Спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну всё то же самое, только с background

Comment: Вижу разницу лишь в интервалах между кадрами, вы про это? Это тоже настраивается в @keyframes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Почему-то у меня сильно проще чем у соседних ответов)

https://webref.ru/css/keyframes

```css
@keyframes online {
  0% { background-color: #6cbe44; }
  57.1% { background-color: white; }
  71.4% { background-color: #6cbe44; }
  85.7% { background-color: white; }
}

.online {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 11px;
    height: 11px;
    border: 1px solid #44b64c;
    background-color: #6cbe44;
    animation: online 1.4s step-end infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="online"></div> - CSS<br/>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXzQC.gif" alt="" /> - GIF
```

Comment: Не проще, а короче)) Потому что у background'а на цвет не действует плавность анимации и опущены альтернативные теги -moz, -o, -webkit (хотя кому они сейчас в 2017 нужны). В любом случае первый комментарий с ответом Ваш)

Answer (score 2):

Да, помимо ключевых слов `from` и `to` синтаксис `@keyframes` включает процентные параметры времени анимации.

```css
.lg-border{
  border: 1px solid LimeGreen;
  width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
}

.online {
  display: block;
 position: relative;
 width: 8px;
 height: 8px;
 border: 1px solid LimeGreen;
 background: LimeGreen;
 -webkit-animation: online 2s steps(5, start) infinite;
 -moz-animation: online 2s steps(5, start) infinite;
 animation: online 2s steps(5, start) infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes online { 
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  30% { opacity: 1; }
  33% { opacity: 0; }
  40% { opacity: 0; }
  43% { opacity: 1; }
  50% { opacity: 1; }
  53% { opacity: 0; }
  60% { opacity: 0; }
  63% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes online { 
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  30% { opacity: 1; }
  33% { opacity: 0; }
  40% { opacity: 0; }
  43% { opacity: 1; }
  50% { opacity: 1; }
  53% { opacity: 0; }
  60% { opacity: 0; }
  63% { opacity: 1; }
}
@keyframes online { 
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  30% { opacity: 1; }
  33% { opacity: 0; }
  40% { opacity: 0; }
  43% { opacity: 1; }
  50% { opacity: 1; }
  53% { opacity: 0; }
  60% { opacity: 0; }
  63% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<div class="lg-border">
 <div class="online"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.online {
  display: block;
 position: relative;
 width: 8px;
 height: 8px;
 border: 1px solid green;
 background: white;
 -webkit-animation: online 2s steps(5, start) infinite;
 -moz-animation: online 2s steps(5, start) infinite;
 animation: online 2s steps(5, start) infinite;
}
@keyframes online { 
  0% { background: white; } 
  20% { background: white; } 
  21% { background: green; } 
  30% { background: green; } 
  31% { background: white; } 
  40% { background: white; } 
  41% { background: green; } 
  50% { background: green; } 
  51% { background: white; } 
  60% { background: white; } 
  61% { background: green; } 
  70% { background: green; } 
  71% { background: white; } 
}
```

```html
<div class="online"></div>
```